# Is there a way to open up a known Outlook email through Java 11? (Web or Local)

Tags: windows, outlook, jakarta-mail, java-11

**Short Version:**
I want to open any specific Outlook email from my Java app, either locally through the Outlook app or through the website on a browser. I already have the email information like folder, message ID, UID, sender, receiver, etc but not the email ID used in the URL of the Outlook website. Does anyone know of a way to do either of these things through Java?

**Long Version:**
I'm creating a software for my company in Java that has a built-in email client for Outlook emails so the emails can be linked with jobs in various ways. So far I've been able to make good progress with the email client section in terms of displaying a list of emails and being able to display a chosen email, but recently I've realized creating a GUI for an email editor (keeping track of reply chains, dragging in images for inline attachments, etc) is quite the gargantuan task to do on my own(JavaFX's HTML Editor could use a lot of work).

My band-aid solution for now is to have my program open the chosen email up through either:

1. Some (Windows 10) system command by calling the Outlook desktop application to show the email by some sort of ID (maybe UID?). I know on some level that this is possible because our company has an old program written in C# that can indeed do that.
2. Opening up the system's default browser with a link to "https://outlook.office365.com/mail/***folder_name***/id/***insert_id_here***". This is my preferred solution.

Here are my problems with each option so far:

1. There doesn't seem to be any resource I could find that provides an answer to this. The closest I can find are threads that explain how to open the default mail application with options to pre-populate to/from/subject/body sections (not to mention you can't pre-populate the body with anything besides text! So much for reply/forward messages with HTML formatting and attachments!). Another problem is that the old program I mentioned displays emails by finding the Outlook application's files (presumably the local OST file). I have no idea how the old program's able to call Outlook to show emails and even then, there's a chance that there's no Java equivalent. I, however, am using JavaMail to load up my mail, as I think it's better to talk to the Outlook mail server to fetch/push mail updates rather than wait for the Outlook app to sync up. This creates a problem because even if I knew how to call Outlook, my application may be more up to date than the Outlook app (especially if Outlook is not already open) and if call before Outlook updates, Outlook wouldn't be able to show it.
2. Again, I can't seem to find a resource for explaining these URL IDs. They're not the same as the mail's UIDs, and they don't seem to be anywhere in the mail's contents when grabbing mail through JavaMail. The most I was able to get from research was that they were called "long IDs", as they were just long strings (seemingly non-sequential) but that might've just been a made-up name from the article as I've found no other references to it. There's a chance that they could be some sort of encoded UID but I didn't see any note of JavaMail having to decrypt to get UIDs in the documentation. I doubt I'd be able to make any more progress with this option, but if there's a solution similar to this (perhaps some sort of script that opens up Outlook online, searches by some identifier, like body contents, and pulls up the first result? Idk much about browser scripts) I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: Maybe you can achieve what you are trying with a JAVA to COM bridge that allows you to call outlook VBA macros?

Comment: @Kartoffel Do you have any recommendations? I looked into Java-COM bridges and the most mentioned one seems to be JACOB but it doesn't seem up-to-date which is a problem since I'm using Java 11. Other bridges I've seen seem like they've stopped updates even farther back.

Comment: I do not have any recommendation, I never built something like this - just thought of the possibility to do this in VBA